# combination of vf page and trigger

Tags: visualforce, trigger

trigger

```
trigger afterInsert on Account(after insert, after update) {
List<Contact> accList = new List<Contact>();
Map<Id,List<Contact>> AccountMap = new Map<Id,List<Contact>>();
    if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        for(Contact con : [SELECT Id,AccountId FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet()]){
            if(!AccountMap.containskey(con.AccountId)){
            AccountMap.put(con.AccountId,new List<Contact>());
            }
            AccountMap.get(con.AccountId).add(con); 

        }
    }

    for(Account c:Trigger.new) {
    system.debug('hfeffht'+c.ID);
        if(!AccountMap.containskey(c.Id)) {
        Contact con = new Contact(LastName=c.Name,
                                    MailingStreet=c.BillingStreet,
                                    MailingState=c.BillingState,

                                    MailingCity=c.BillingCity,
                                    MailingPostalCode=c.BillingPostalCode,
                                    MailingCountry=c.BillingCountry,
                                    AccountId=c.ID);
                accList.add(con);
                system.debug('AccountId'+con.AccountId);
        }else{
            for(Contact con : AccountMap.get(c.Id)){ 

                    con.MailingStreet = c.BillingStreet;
                    con.MailingState=c.BillingState;

                    con.MailingCity = c.BillingCity;
                    con.MailingPostalCode = c.BillingPostalCode;
                    con.MailingCountry = c.BillingCountry;
                    accList.add(con);
                }

        }
    }
    try {
    if(Trigger.isInsert){
       upsert accList;
        }else if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        update accList;

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.debug('errormesg ' + ex.getCause());
    }
}
```

class

```
public with sharing class AccBillToConMai {
public Account a{get;set;}
    public AccBillToConMai(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
a=(Account)controller.getRecord();
    }

    public pageReference save(){

    try {

    insert a;

        ID acctID = a.ID;
system.debug('acctID '+acctID);
    // Add a contact to this account.
    Contact con = new Contact(

        LastName=a.Name,
                MailingStreet=a.BillingStreet,
                MailingCity=a.BillingCity,
                MailingPostalCode=a.BillingPostalCode,
                MailingCountry=a.BillingCountry,
        AccountId=acctID);
        if(a.Industry=='Construction'){
        con.Company_Name__c=a.Name;
        con.Company_Phone__c=a.Phone;
        insert con;
        return null;
        }else if(a.Industry=='Education'){
        con.University__c='svc';
        con.private__c=true;
        insert con;
        }else if(a.Industry=='Electronics'){
        con.devices__c='Ac';
        con.review__c='2';
        insert con;
        }

        insert con;
} catch(DmlException e) {
    System.debug('An unexpected error has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());
}


    pageReference pf=new pageReference ('/'+a.Id);
    pf.setRedirect(true);
    return pf;
    }

}
```

,problem is when i create account record from vf page means,creating two contacts,from ui works fine,.i want to restrict ,it must create only one record.please suggest me how to do it,am a fresher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

trigger afterInsert on Account(after insert, after update) {
List accList = new List();
Map> AccountMap = new Map>();
system.debug('AccBillToConMai.stoptrigger2'+AccBillToConMai.stoptrigger);
//AccBillToConMai.stoptrigger=false;
if(!AccBillToConMai.stoptrigger){
system.debug('AccBillToConMai.stoptrigger1'+AccBillToConMai.stoptrigger);
    if(Trigger.isUpdate){
        for(Contact con : [SELECT Id,AccountId FROM Contact WHERE AccountId IN :Trigger.newMap.keySet()]){
            if(!AccountMap.containskey(con.AccountId)){
            AccountMap.put(con.AccountId,new List());
            }
            AccountMap.get(con.AccountId).add(con);

```
    }
}

for(Account c:Trigger.new) {
system.debug('hfeffht'+c.ID);
    if(!AccountMap.containskey(c.Id)) {
    Contact con = new Contact(LastName=c.Name,
                                MailingStreet=c.BillingStreet,
                                MailingState=c.BillingState,

                                MailingCity=c.BillingCity,
                                MailingPostalCode=c.BillingPostalCode,
                                MailingCountry=c.BillingCountry,
                                AccountId=c.ID);
            accList.add(con);
            system.debug('AccountId'+con.AccountId);
    }else{
        for(Contact con : AccountMap.get(c.Id)){ 

                con.MailingStreet = c.BillingStreet;
                con.MailingState=c.BillingState;

                con.MailingCity = c.BillingCity;
                con.MailingPostalCode = c.BillingPostalCode;
                con.MailingCountry = c.BillingCountry;
                accList.add(con);
            }

    }
}
try {

   upsert accList;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
    System.debug('errormesg ' + ex.getCause());
}
}
```

}

public with sharing class AccBillToConMai {
public Account a{get;set;}

public static Boolean stoptrigger=false;
    public AccBillToConMai(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
a=(Account)controller.getRecord();
    }

```
public pageReference save(){
    try {
stoptrigger=true;
```

if(stoptrigger==true){
    insert a;

```
    ID acctID = a.ID;
```

system.debug('acctID '+acctID);
    // Add a contact to this account.
    Contact con = new Contact(

```
    LastName=a.Name,
            MailingStreet=a.BillingStreet,
            MailingCity=a.BillingCity,
            MailingPostalCode=a.BillingPostalCode,
            MailingCountry=a.BillingCountry,
    AccountId=acctID);
    if(a.Industry=='Construction'){
    con.Company_Name__c=a.Name;
    con.Company_Phone__c=a.Phone;
    insert con;
    return null;
    }else if(a.Industry=='Education'){
    con.University__c='svc';
    con.private__c=true;
    insert con;
    }else if(a.Industry=='Electronics'){
    con.devices__c='Ac';
    con.review__c='2';
    insert con;
    }

    insert con;
    }
```

} catch(DmlException e) {
    System.debug('An unexpected error has occurred: ' + e.getMessage());

} 
    pageReference pf=new pageReference ('/'+a.Id);
    pf.setRedirect(true);
    return pf;
    }

}

Comment: please check my answer and mark as solution

Answer (score 0):

Create one custom field boolean named isFlag (example) to indicate if the record is inserted from Visualforce page .When insert through visualforce page, isFlag is true the trigger will skip the insertion.

```
trigger afterInsert on Account(after insert, after update) {

      for(Account c:Trigger.new) {
         //check the flag it won't process the record that inserted from VF.
        //isFlag== false mean the record is not from VF.
         if(c.isFlag==false){ 

            //proceed logic for trigger processing

          }
       }

}
```

Comment: Creating a custom field just for this scenario is a bad practice. Can create a static boolean variable in controller class and use that in trigger to check whether it got initiated from VF.

Comment: i got it using static boolean variable,thanq all

Answer (score 0):

If you need only one Contact Created each time, why did you write the code to insert contact in your class? Just insert the account record, it will invoke the trigger and in trigger you already have the code to insert Contact. If required, move the if else conditions from apex class to trigger.